Redirect the learner to a specific chapter on vimeo
I'm integrating the Vimeo API into my application, where users can watch a video that includes different chapters. After watching, they will take a quiz. If the user answers any question incorrectly, I want to redirect them to a specific chapter in the video to review that content.
I’ve checked the Vimeo documentation, and it mentions that if the video's privacy is set to "Hide from Vimeo," the chapter links will not function. Viewers trying to access a chapter through a link will receive an error message.
Given this limitation, is there another way to redirect users to specific chapters within an embedded video, even with the privacy setting? How can I achieve this?
